# How to display a range list in descending order in Python?

Tags: python, list, reverse

I'm trying to display a list in descending order:

```
answer = range(num1, num2, div)
print(reversed(list(answer)))
```

But my output is displaying `<list_reverseiterator object at 0x000002385b687Fa0>`.

How would I display my list in descending order?

For example:

```
[100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
```

Comment: You need to convert the iterator to list `print(list(reversed(list(answer))))`

Comment: Although the linked answer is sufficient to answer your question, I wanted to add that if you want to generate the list using the `range()` function, you can simply use the function to generate the reversed list `range(num2, num1, -div)`.